# How to find the coefficient of correlation

Tags: statistics, regression, variance, covariance, correlation

This question was appeared in my practice test last week and i was bit confused about it, how to approach this question as a whole.

Q. If a linear relation $ +  +  = 0$ exists between the variables $X$ and $Y$ and $ < 0$ , then
find coefficient of correlation between $X$ and $Y$.

I have two doubts:

1. ax < 0, what does it means and what effect does it shows on the answer, like if it is ab < 0 rather than ax < 0. what effect does it had on the solution.
2. How to approach these kind of questions.

What is Know is

1. $$r = \frac {cov(x,y)}{\sqrt {\sigma_x^2}.\sqrt {\sigma_y^2}}$$

$$r = \frac {cov(x,y)}{\sigma_x.\sigma_y}$$

Thanks in advance

Edit : 
this is the solution I produce

$a(x - \bar x) + b(y - \bar y) = 0$
$$(x - \bar x) = \frac {-b}{a}(y-\bar y)$$
$$cov(X,Y) =  \frac {1}{n} \Sigma (x-\bar x)(y-\bar y)$$
$$=\frac {-b}{a} \frac {1}{n} \Sigma (y-\bar y)^2$$
$$=\frac {-b}{a} \sigma_y^2$$
$$\sigma_x^2 = \frac {1}{n} \Sigma (x-\bar x)^2$$
$$ =\frac {b^2}{a^2} (\frac {1}{n} \Sigma (y-\bar y)^2)$$
$$r = \frac {cov(x,y)}{\sigma_x.\sigma_y}$$
$$=\frac {\frac {-b}{a} \sigma_y^2}{\sqrt {\frac {b^2}{a^2} \sigma_y^2} .\sigma_y}$$
$=-1$ or $1$
as
$$\sqrt {\frac {b^2}{a^2}} = \vert\frac{b}{a}\vert$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks sir for improving my question.

Answer (score 1):

Well if there is a linear relation like that then $cor(X,Y)$ is either $1$ or $-1$.

$cor(X,Y)$ is $1$ when $a$ and $b$ are of opposite signs.

$cor(X,Y)$ is $-1$ when $a$ and $b$ are of same signs.

Comment: i have edited the question and uploaded my solution please take a look at it.

Comment: @AlexEd your workout seems correct to me. You can notice that it leads to the same conclusion I pointed out in my answer.